# Generate GUID at runtime without using form in NetSuite

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

Hye there,

I'm trying to prepare a scheduled script in NetSuite which will pick a particular directory from file cabinet and deploy it on SFTP server. I'm using 2.0 module and here is my code -

```
require(["N/sftp",'N/record','N/file'], function(sftp,record,file) {

    function onRequest() {
        var myPwdGuid = "13139ac567b14f74bdaXXXXXXX";
        var myHostKey = "AAAAB3NzaC1ycXXXXX";

        var connection = sftp.createConnection({
            username: 'Your user name',
            passwordGuid: myPwdGuid,
            url: 'Your host name',
            directory: '/directory to upload files/',
            hostKey: myHostKey
        });

        var myFileToUpload = file.create({
            name: 'originalname.js',
            fileType: file.fileType.PLAINTEXT,
            contents: 'I am a test file. Hear me roar.'
        });

        connection.upload({
            directory: 'relative/path/to/remote/dir',
            filename: 'newFileNameOnServer.js',
            file: myFileToUpload,
            replaceExisting: true
        });

        var downloadedFile = connection.download({
            directory: 'relative/path/to/file',
            filename: 'downloadMe.js'
        });
    }

    onRequest();
    return {
        onRequest: onRequest
    };
});
```

Now the issue is when i try to run these lines of code i get an error saying "AN_ERROR_OCCURRED_WHILE_DECRYPT_PASSWORDGUID". 
What i've found so far through my research is GUID can only be generated by SuitLet form having credential field which will again require GET and POST method. However i Dont want to create a suitelet and invoke it manually in order to generate GUID. All i want to to do is - Run a scheduled script which will Establish connection to SFTP. Pick a directory in file cabinet and upload it on SFTP.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Its easier and faster than you might think. Take the below code and load it to NetSuite. Create a script file and deployment quick, run the SUITElet to get your GUID, paste that value into your Scheduled Script and don't mess with it again unless the password changes.

```
/**
*@NApiVersion 2.x
*@NScriptType Suitelet
*/
define([
'N/ui/serverWidget',
'N/https'
],
function (
    ui,
    https
) {
    var HOST_KEY_TOOL_URL = 'https://ursuscode.com/tools/sshkeyscan.php?url=';

    function getFormTemplate() {
        var form;
        form = ui.createForm({
            title: 'Password Form'
        });
        form.addSubmitButton({
            label: 'Submit'
        });

        return form;
    }

    function addSelectorFields(form) {
        var select = form.addField({
            id: 'selectaction',
            type: ui.FieldType.SELECT,
            label: 'Select Action'
        });
        select.addSelectOption({
            value: 'getpasswordguid',
            text: 'Get Password GUID'
        });
        select.addSelectOption({
            value: 'gethostkey',
            text: 'Get Host Key'
        });
        return form;
    }

    function addPasswordGUID1Fields(form) {
        var frm = form;

        frm.addField({
            id: 'restricttoscriptids',
            type: ui.FieldType.TEXT,
            label: 'Restrict To Script Ids'
        }).isMandatory = true;
        frm.addField({
            id: 'restricttodomains',
            type: ui.FieldType.TEXT,
            label: 'Restrict To Domains'
        }).isMandatory = true;

        return frm;
    }

    function addPasswordGUID2Fields(form, restrictToScriptIds, restrictToDomains) {
        form.addCredentialField({
            id: 'password',
            label: 'Password',
            restrictToScriptIds: restrictToScriptIds.replace(' ', '').split(','),
            restrictToDomains: restrictToDomains.replace(' ', '').split(',')
        });
        return form;
    }

    function addHostKeyFields(form) {
        form.addField({
            id: 'url',
            type: ui.FieldType.TEXT,
            label: 'URL (Required)'
        });

        form.addField({
            id: 'port',
            type: ui.FieldType.INTEGER,
            label: 'Port (Optional)'
        });

        form.addField({
            id: 'hostkeytype',
            type: ui.FieldType.TEXT,
            label: 'Type (Optional)'
        });
        return form;
    }

    function onRequest(option) {
        var method;
        var form;
        var selectAction;
        var port;
        var hostKeyType;
        var restricttoscriptids;
        var restricttodomains;
        var password;

        var theResponse;
        var myUrl;
        var url;
        method = option.request.method;
        form = getFormTemplate(method);
        if (method === 'GET') {
            form = addSelectorFields(form);
        }
        if (method === 'POST') {
            selectAction = option.request.parameters.selectaction;
            if (selectAction === 'getpasswordguid') {
                form = addPasswordGUID1Fields(form);

            } else if (selectAction === 'gethostkey') {
                form = addHostKeyFields(form);
            } else {
                password = option.request.parameters.password;
                url = option.request.parameters.url;
                port = option.request.parameters.port;
                hostKeyType = option.request.parameters.hostkeytype;
                restricttoscriptids = option.request.parameters.restricttoscriptids;
                restricttodomains = option.request.parameters.restricttodomains;

                if (restricttoscriptids && restricttodomains) {
                    form = addPasswordGUID2Fields(form, restricttoscriptids, restricttodomains);
                }

                if (password) {
                    form.addField({
                        id: 'passwordguidresponse',
                        type: ui.FieldType.LONGTEXT,
                        label: 'PasswordGUID Response',
                        displayType: ui.FieldDisplayType.INLINE
                    }).defaultValue = password;
                }
                if (url) {
                    myUrl = HOST_KEY_TOOL_URL + url + '&port=' + port + '&type=' + hostKeyType;
                    theResponse = https.get({ url: myUrl }).body;
                    form.addField({
                        id: 'hostkeyresponse',
                        type: ui.FieldType.LONGTEXT,
                        label: 'Host Key Response',
                        displayType: ui.FieldDisplayType.INLINE
                    }).defaultValue = theResponse;
                }
            }
        }
        option.response.writePage(form);
    }
    return {
        onRequest: onRequest
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The ability to directly hard-code an SFTP password is not supported in NetSuite. NetSuite uses password tokenization in order to prevent scripts from having access to user credentials. For this reason, only an authenticated user may store a password, and a script may only access it via an identifier (GUID/Token).